# Polymorphic Code-First Models and Querying

Tags: c#, inheritance, ef-code-first, ef-core-2.1

I'm trying to build a survey system and want to use inheritance on the `Question` model, using code-first migrations.

```
public class MultipleChoiceQuestion : Question {
  public bool AllowMultipleSelection { get; set; }
  public List<MCQOption> Options { get; set; }
}
```

Even if I add another `DbSet<MultipleChoiceQuestion>`, it doesn't appear in the migrations. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't add anything that would result in additional columns, so another table isn't needed (presumably the `MCQOption` has a FK back to `Question`)

Comment: @juharr guess I oversimplified my sample code. Fixed it to solve the case you mentioned.